# How can I call the fields of this Object Array with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to call these Arrays in JavaScript:

In json_encode:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "resultaQuantidade": 5,
    "1": {
        "contador": 1,
        "id": "2",
        "imagem_capa": "\/images\/boruto.jpg",
        "titulo_en": "Boruto: Naruto Next Generations",
        "status": "ESPERANDO",
        "total_ep": "12",
        "numero_ep_cp": "??",
        "tipo": "NOVEL",
        "nota": "0.00"
    },
    "2": {
        "contador": 2,
        "id": "1",
        "imagem_capa": "\/images\/sword.jpg",
        "titulo_en": "Sword Art Online",
        "status": "COMPLETO",
        "total_ep": "24",
        "numero_ep_cp": "25",
        "tipo": "TV",
        "nota": "8"
    }
}
```

In var_dump:

```
  array(4) {
  ["result"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["resultaQuantidade"]=>
  int(5)
  [1]=>
  array(9) {
    ["contador"]=>
    int(1)
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["imagem_capa"]=>
    string(18) "/images/boruto.jpg"
    ["titulo_en"]=>
    string(31) "Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"
    ["status"]=>
    string(9) "ESPERANDO"
    ["total_ep"]=>
    string(2) "12"
    ["numero_ep_cp"]=>
    string(2) "??"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(5) "NOVEL"
    ["nota"]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(9) {
    ["contador"]=>
    int(2)
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["imagem_capa"]=>
    string(17) "/images/sword.jpg"
    ["titulo_en"]=>
    string(16) "Sword Art Online"
    ["status"]=>
    string(8) "COMPLETO"
    ["total_ep"]=>
    string(2) "24"
    ["numero_ep_cp"]=>
    string(2) "25"
    ["tipo"]=>
    string(2) "TV"
    ["nota"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/CarregarAnimesListaT.php",
        data: {
        'offset': flag,
        'limit': 3,
        'usuarioid': usuarioid
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(){
            document.getElementById("loading-space-js").style.display = "block";
        },
        success: function (data) {  
            var dados = data;
            $("tbody tr").last().remove();

            for(var i = 0; i < data.resultaQuantidade; i++){
                $("tbody").append('<tr><td>'+data.dados[i].id+'</td><td>'+data.dados[i].name+'</td><td>'+data.dados[i].email+'</td><td>'+data.dados[i].senha+'</td></tr>');
                document.getElementById("loading-space-js").style.display = "none";
                flag += 3;
            }

            var conta = $("tbody tr").length;

            if(conta == data.resultaQuantidade){
                $("button.carregar-mais").hide();
            }

        },
        error: function(errorThrown2)
        { 
            swal("Opps!", "Ocorreu algum erro no sistema de carregamento de lista! [" + errorThrown2 + "]", "error"); 
        }
});
```

Comment: A good first step is to try `console.log(data.dados)` which will probably return `undefined` - then try `console.log(dados)` which is where your data will actually live, from what I saw glancing over your code.

Please add more specifics about what you are trying to accomplish and and post the errors you are encountering.

Comment: There's no `dados` property in the JSON. The indexes start at `1`, not `0`. And even though it says `resultaQuantidade: 5`, there are only `2` numbered properties.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to mix numeric and named indexes in the same array. Put the numeric array in its own property (such as `dados`).

Comment: If you put the numeric array in its own property, you don't need the `resultaQuantidade` property. You can just use `data.dados.length`.

Comment: @Barmar - he sets `dados=data` in the javascript, but yes, the `resultaQuantidae` value is going to cause problems given the data posted.

Comment: @JeremyAnderson I know that, but then he uses `data.dados`, not just `dados`.

Comment: Agreed, @Barmar - @Thiago Araújo `data.dados` is your biggest problem, here. Keep hacking, please add more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I used the resultQuantity to count the total record in the database, but the problem is not this, I wanted to show the value of the array by calling it in javaScript, type the value of "titulo_en", so I wanted call it in javaScript.

Comment: These codes are part of a scrolling system with PHP, json, Ajax and Mysqli, where "/ajax/loadAnimeListT.php" searches the database records and becomes an array of objects, so far so good, my problem is to do JavaScript array properties.

The question is how to call the properties of the array.

Array
["titulo_en": "Boruto: Naruto Next Generations"]

JavaScript:
data.titulo_en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your "success" function with:

```
success: function (data) {  
    var dados = data;
    $("tbody tr").last().remove();

    var conta = 0;
    var len = Number(data.resultaQuantidade); // convert to number
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var obj = data[String(i)]; // String = convert number to string

        // resultaQuantidade may be incorrect
        if(obj){
            $("tbody").append('<tr><td>'+obj.id+'</td><td>'+obj.name+'</td><td>'+obj.email+'</td><td>'+obj.senha+'</td></tr>');
            document.getElementById("loading-space-js").style.display = "none";
            conta++;

            //flag += 3;
        }

    }

    if(conta == len){
        $("button.carregar-mais").hide();
    }

},
```

Comment: I did what you asked for and I tested it here, it does not show an error in the console, but it shows an error in itself "$ .ajax ({});" where it turns on activates this error:

error: function (errorThrown2)
 {
swal ("Opps!", "There was an error in the list loading system!" ["+ errorThrown2 +"] "," error ");
 }

Comment: It worked, I modified some things to the right using its base of code, thank you